# How to fix header manipulation cookies using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, cookies, fortify

My JavaScript code:

```
function CookieSetting(name, value) {
    var today = new Date();
    today.setTime( today.getTime() );
    var expires = 28;
    expires = expires * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    var expires_date = new Date( today.getTime() + (expires) );
    document.cookie = name+"="+escape( value ) +
    ( ( expires ) ?";
   domain="+window.location.hostname+";path=/;expires="+expires_date.toGMTString() : "" )
}
```

It's working fine, but when I run the Fortify tool, it is showing this error:

> The method CookieSetting() includes unvalidated data in an HTTP response header.
>
> This enables attacks such as cache-poisoning  cross-site scripting  cross-user defacement 
>    page hijacking  cookie manipulation or open redirect.
>
> Including unvalidated data in an HTTP response header can enable cache-poisoning  cross-site scripting, cross-user defacement, page hijacking, cookie manipulation or open redirect.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that if value comes from user input he can attack your http headers.

If he is able to insert CR (carriage return, also given by %0d or \r) into the *value*, then he can add another **headers** into your http request (because http headers are separated by CR).
Source: [Nice web article about those attacks](http://www.hpenterprisesecurity.com/vulncat/en/vulncat/javascript/header_manipulation_cookies.html).

**Solution A)**

I've looked into and [existing implementation of javascript setCookie](https://code.google.com/p/cookies/) and what they do is:

```
optionsString = ( ( expires ) ? "; domain="+window.location.hostname+";path=/;expires="+expires_date.toGMTString() : "" 
document.cookie = cookieName + '=' + encodeURIComponent( value ) + optionsString;
```

But if you do this, you would need opposite method for getting the cookie - getCookie() in which you would do **decodeURIComponent()** before returning the value.

I would try to to sanitize your value by the **encodeURIComponent()** method.

**Solution B)**

Sanitize the **name** parameter

Another thing which you can try is just sanitize your name by the escape method, maybe this is why fortify tool is complaining:

```
document.cookie = window.escape(name)+"="+window.escape(value) + ...
```

Comment: Tomor,Could you please edit my js function so that it should not change my functionality.

Comment: Tomor,here what is optionsSting in your answer?

Comment: optionsString is string with options for the cookie - path, expires etc (I've updated my answer)